# Replace strips of tongue and groove subfloor

Tags: floor, subfloor

A corner in my laundry room is sinking/rotted, the construction is tongue and groove with particle board on top. I suspect the rot probably goes into the tongue and groove planks.

How do I replace sections? The spacing on the support members looks like it's 4ft, will I need to cut the floor until I hit a support?

Comment: Perhaps a photo or two would help.  I'm having trouble understanding your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to get in to it and see how damaged it really is. If its just the particle board (will disintegrate with water exposure unless sealed) then you can just cut the damaged section out and replace.

If its the tongue and groove planks that are damaged you have to replace between joists, you cant have a seam floating in the middle of the floor unsupported.

Some photos would help me make more recommendations.

Comment: I'm kind of terrified of this turning into a larger project than I am comfortable with. If it was a standard plywood floor I would have done it already

Comment: @FourierFlux Maybe indicate in your original question what the "terror" is about removing T&G that's not there if you're pulling "standard plywood", as that seems to be the real crux of your question.